# Retrieving File Data in CodeIgniter by clicking on an anchor tag via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this question. How do i get a data from a file when an anchor is clicked,

this is my function in controller.

```
function change_log_year_view($year) {
    $file = $this->get_file($year);
    $message = $this->generate_message_body(read_file($file));


    if (!empty($year)) {
        $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $data['message'] = $message;
        $this->load->view('change_log_view', $data);
    }
```

This is the View.

```
        echo anchor('changelog/change_log_year_view/' . '2013', 'Change Log 2013');
        echo '|' . anchor('changelog/change_log_year_view/' . '2014', 'Change Log 2014');
        echo '|' . anchor('changelog/change_log_year_view/' . '2015', 'Change Log 2015');
        <text style="white-space: pre-line;"  id="message"><?php echo $message; ?></text>
```

This way worked. but is it possible if i use jquery or javascript?, if it is possible how does the script looks like, Thank You.

Comment: no. it's not possible. javascript runs in the client browser, your CI code runs on the server. you need to use ajax to link the two.

Comment: note it, but how does the script looks like if i use ajax?

Answer (score 1):

First of all change set default value of `$year` parameter to `$year = ''` to prevent getting error.

Basically your controller should echo out data, Not return. So echo `$message` out directly.

```
echo $this->generate_message_body(read_file($file));
```

**PHP *(Controller file)*:**

```
function change_log_year_view($year = '')
{
    if (empty($year)) {
        die('Optional Error Message...');
    }

    $file = $this->get_file($year);
    $message = $this->generate_message_body(read_file($file));

    // Is this necessary? I assume NO,
    // because you didn't show any usage of $id variable in your question.
    // $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');

    // $data['message'] = $message;
    // $this->load->view('change_log_view', $data);

    echo $message;
}
```

**Note:**
The `$this->get_file()` and `$this->generate_message_body()` are OP's own method (**NOT** CI core)

**JS *([Using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))*:**

```
$.ajax({
    type     : 'GET',  // or 'POST', whatever you want.
    dataType : 'text', // output_value will be a plain text string.
    url      : 'YOUR_ANCHOR_TAG_URL',
    success  : function(output_value){
        // output_value is the result.
        // do what you want with it.
    }
});
```

**Note:**
Insert your controller URL address (do NOT forget the `YEAR` variable) instead of `YOUR_ANCHOR_TAG_URL` phrase.

You can get URLs automatically by `$('your_link_selector').attr('href');`

## **Just as a Demo:**

*Set `class="ajax-call"` to your `<a>` tags.*

```
$('.ajax-call').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type     : 'GET',
        dataType : 'text',
        url      : _this.attr('href'),
        success  : function(output_value){
            // output_value is the result.
            // do what you want with it.
        }
    });
}
```

*As a side-question:* What is the `<text>` tag? A new generation of Markups? I didn't see this before, use `<span>` for `inline` element or `<p>` for `block-level`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using jQuery ajax. You can call your controller method using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax in CI like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ajax with CI</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ci_link').on('click',function(){
        // get link href string
        var linkHref = $(this).attr('href');
        // get year from string
        var getYearFromLinkHref = linkHref.split('/')[2];

        // your ajax param to send CI Controller
        var sendAjaxDataToController = {year:getYearFromLinkHref};

        // if you are using CSRF token in CI then
        // token name CI Function
        var csrftokenname = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>";
        // token value CI Function
        var csrftokenvalue = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>";

        var sendAjaxDataToController = {year:getYearFromLinkHref,csrftokenname:csrftokenvalue};

        // Ajax Code Start
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",           
            data: $.param(sendAjaxDataToController ),
            url: "http://www.yoursite.com/Changelog/change_log_year_view",          
            success: ajaxSucceess,
            error: ajaxError
        });
        // Ajax Code End

        // Code for Success Handler
        function ajaxSucceess(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }

        // Code for Error Handler
        function ajaxError(response) {
            console.log(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**// Your Controller Code**

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Changelog extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Chnage Log Year Function
     */
    function change_log_year_view() {
        // get year data from ajax post
        $year = $this->input->post('year');     
        $file = $this->get_file($year);
        $message = $this->generate_message_body(read_file($file));
        if (!empty($year)) {
            $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $data['message'] = $message;
            $this->load->view('change_log_view', $data);
        }

}
?>
```

**// Your Anchor Code should like this:**

```
<?php 
// create array attribute for link
$linkAttr = array('title'=>'your link title','class'=>'ci_link');
// show a link with attribute
echo anchor('changelog/change_log_year_view/2013', 'Change Log 2013', $linkAttr);
?>
```

**// Your CI application/config/autoload.php**

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Helper Files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
*/

$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```